# Creating a dataframe in R based on different condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe that contains 1 year's reading of 1 hour duration for each different variable, like

```
Date                  Area        Application        Type         Reading
2015-01-01 00:00:00  Livingroom   Heating            Electricity  0
.
.
2015-12-30 00:00:00  Livingroom   Heating            Electricity  0

2015-01-01 00:00:00  Livingroom   Heating            Gas          3
.
.
2015-12-30 00:00:00  Livingroom   Heating            Gas          2

2015-01-01 00:00:00  Livingroom   Lighting           Electricity  1
.
.
2015-12-30 00:00:00  Livingroom   Lighting           Electricity  2

2015-01-01 00:00:00  Livingroom   Lighting           Gas          3
.
.
2015-12-30 00:00:00  Livingroom   Lighting           Gas          2
```

And the file will be extended for each year three area (living room, bedroom, hallway), three application (heating, lighting, appliances) and two type (electricity and Gas). Also, for heating, electricity will be 0 and for lighting, gas will be zero.

My question is how to do it in one go (using some for loop or any other function)

I have managed to create this data file with this script:

```
dates<-seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2015-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("2015-12-31 23", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  by="hour"
)

df11 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(dates), ncol = 5)) 
# Define names of cols and add column
names(df11) <- c("Date", "Area", "Application", "Type", "Reading")
df11$Date <- dates

df11$Area<-"Livingroom"
df11$Application<-"Heating"
df11$Type<-"Electricity"
df11$Reading<-0
```

This is how i created 18 different files for different variables and then bind them together at the end.

```
newdataset<-rbind(df11,df12,df13,df14,df15,df16,df21,df22,df23,df24,df25,df26,df31,df32,df33,df34,df35,df36)
```

I know this is very lazy and dirty kind of script. I really want to know how to do it nicely using loop or some other method.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want all combinations of the three factors, right? Could you elaborate on how you want `Reading` to be defined?

Comment: David H 
Readings will be created randomly, i use the function `sample(1:4, 8760, replace=TRUE)` As i said for heating, electricity will be 0 and for lighting gas will be 0 rest all data will be generated by `sample` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `expand.grid()` to get all combinations of your factors in a (large) dataframe:

```
df <- expand.grid( Date = dates , Area = c("Livingroom" , "Bedroom" , "Hallway") , 
                   Application = c("Heating" , "Lighting" , "Appliances") , Type = c("Electricity" , "Gas")  )
```

The values fro `Reading` can then be added:

```
df$Reading <- ifelse( (df$Application == "Heating" & df$Type == "Electricity") | (df$Application == "Lighting" & df$Type == "Gas") , 0 , sample(1:4, nrow(df) , replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: David H 
This is very interesting and easy to understand script. Thank you very much for that. Just a little query, currently, this script  displays the data for each area and one application first then for each area and 2nd and then third application. How can I create all data for living room corresponding to heating, lighting and appliance first and then for bedroom and then at the end for hallway.